# Ruby hash dig or return nil if not possible

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have to access an array that is fairly deep into a JSON object to then map the contents of the array and return the new array.

If the array exists -> mapped array contents

If the array is empty... OR the array doesn't exist -> [] (empty array)

I've tried doing a dig and map...

`the_data.dig('foo', 'bar', 0, 'baz', 'fuzz').map ...`

`fuzz` is my array I want to map.

But the part that fails is the part after `bar` because it is an empty array here.

How can I safely fall back here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd simply go for

```
the_data.dig('foo', 'bar', 0, 'baz', 'fuzz').to_a.map
```

as

```
nil.to_a == []
```

You'll try to map an empty array, which will simply not do anything and return an empty array again.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537) `&.` (introduced in Ruby 2.3).

```
some_variable&.some_method
# is equivalent to
some_variable.nil? ? nil : some_variable.some_method
# or
some_variable.some_method unless some_variable.nil?
```

Since both [*Array#dig*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-dig) and [*Hash#dig*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-dig) return `nil` if any intermediate step is `nil` this should meet your requirement. Skipping the *map* call if the resulting value is `nil`.

```
the_data
  .dig('foo', 'bar', 0, 'baz', 'fuzz')
  &.map ...
```

---

Another option is to save the data in a variable and use an *if* statement.

```
if fuzz = the_data.dig('foo', 'bar', 0, 'baz', 'fuzz')
  fuzz.map ...
end
```

---

Or if you're working in a method and can't proceed without the value you can add a guard that returns the method if the value is missing.

```
##
# Does something.
# 
# @param the_data [Hash] a JSON object that ...
# @return [Array<Object>, nil] an array containing ... 
#   or nil if the JSON object doesn't has the correct structure 
def some_method(the_data)
  fuzz = the_data.dig('foo', 'bar', 0, 'baz', 'fuzz') or return
  fuzz.map ...
end
```

Comment: Using a default value would also work. `fuzz = the_data.dig('foo', 'bar', 0, 'baz', 'fuzz') || []` working further with the `fuzz` variable.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. Will definitely be back here for reference in the future :D

Comment: @CarySwoveland Did you see my example? The safe navigator is not meant for *dig*. It's meant to only call *map* if *dig* doesn't results in `nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Np, we all have those days. ;-)